# JavaScript, Eval, and New -- poor man's factory

Tags: javascript, eval, factory-pattern

Rare cases aside, [eval() is considered bad practice](http://www.google.com/search?q=jslint%20eval%20is%20evil) in JavaScript.

I've just come across a fragment of code that takes a string and constructs an object by that type name.  Error checking, business logic, and context for doing so removed, here's what it looks like:

```
function factory(klass) {
  eval("var obj = new " + klass + "()"); // Is there a better way?
  return obj;
}
```

Is there a better (safer, cleaner, and/or faster) way to accomplish the class creation **without using eval**?

I'm looking for a *generic* way to create a class by its *name*.

e.g., Imagine, for instance, another part of the code dynamically loads JavaScript files, generates code, or allows user extensions, but then some other part of the code needs to make that class without the factory having prior knowledge of its existence.

Comment: Error checking, et. al., was removed for the sake of making a terse example on StackOverflow -- fret not.

Comment: Without getting into too much of the why behind it, klass is a string.  The ponderance was to find a way to do the logical equivalent, using the same input, without using eval() to pull off the stunt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register classes with your factory object and than create them by string name:

```
var allClasses = [];
allClasses["MyClass"] = function(){return new MyClass();}
allClasses["MyStruct"] = function() {return {F1:"", F2:42};}

function factory(klass) 
{
    if (!allClasses[klass]) throw "Bad name!";
    return allClasses[klass]();
}
```

Comment: I'd really like to give split credit on this.  David Titarenco indicated in his comments that it is not possible to do what I was trying to do without eval.  Alexei Levenkov managed to give the next closest thing, taking a string as I needed, returning classes from a factory object.  So I'm accepting this as the best way presented so far to get around not using eval().  Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a situation where error-checking IS important and you should not have removed it. Say we go with @Gabi's "hard factory" solution:

```
function hardfactory(klass) {
  var obj = new klass();
  return obj;
}

try {
var x = hardfactory(asdf); // this will break unless
                           // we wrap every single hardfactory() call in a try-catch
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
} // who wants to do this every time we invoke hardfactory? not I
```

Now lets look at your original "soft factory" solution:

```
function softfactory(klass) {
  try {
      eval("var obj = new " + klass + "()");
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
  return obj;
}

var y = softfactory("asdf"); // this will not break
                             // since we do the try catch inside the softfactory()
```

The `eval()` call is well-warranted in this case. It's important to understand that every language construct (yes, even `eval()`) is useful and part of the language for a reason. The fact that some people overuse it or use it in the wrong circumstances doesn't mean it's not a very powerful tool in the right ones.

Comment: Also, you should make it clear that `eval` requires you to be careful with the input: if `klass` was something like `function(){}; /* your evil code */ (function(){})`, you're in for some trouble

Comment: So, error-checking aside, which I agree with but is not part of question pertaining to eval, is this answer confirming that this is one of the few acceptable cases for using eval, and that this is the proper way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: If you're asking if there's a way to pass a string to a function and get the object representation of the string then no, there's no way of doing that without eval.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need eval. You can simply pass the object instead of its name, and use `var obj = new klass()`. Voilà

```
function factory(klass) {
  var obj = new klass();
  return obj;
}

function C() {...}
C.prototype = {...}

factory(C);
```

Comment: It seems to me they *want* to pass a variable's name, a string. That's what the question is about.

Comment: @katspaugh The question says clearly "Is there a better (safer, cleaner, and/or faster) way to __accomplish the class creation without using eval?__". Reading comprehension

Comment: Yet there is a way to accomplish class creation provided a name and a namespace, the bracket notation. And it's a bit closer to the original function, don't you think?

Comment: @katspaugh no, I don't think that. The OP doesn't state anywhere a _namespace_. The class definition may be very well in any outer scope level, so bracket notation fails. Also, if you think you have a better solution, post an answer; the OP may appreciate it.

Comment: More info: the string is coming from an external source, no object instance exists at the time the factory is called.